# Play Video From URL in WatchOS 2

Tags: ios, xcode, video, apple-watch, watchos-2

So recently Apple® released the second operating system for their Apple Watch®. With this update, Apple Watch® can now have HTTP requests and internet connection by itself. They added the

```
 WKInterfaceMovie
```

Which loads a video from a url with the method

"
     - setMovieURL:
Declaration (New in watchOS 2.0)

SWIFT

```
  func setMovieURL(_ URL: NSURL)
```

OBJECTIVE-C

```
- (void)setMovieURL:(NSURL * _Nonnull)URL
```

"

If I input a URL with any .mov video online. The WKInterfaceMovie closes automatically. Sometimes the "Downloading" circle comes and begins to load up but I haven't been able to show up the remote video (Not stored in the Apple Watch®)

I would be amazed if someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. It works for local videos which I put directly to the Watchkit Extension but it doesn't work with remote videos.

There is other option - download the video manually and then play it but App Group needs to be created for this and I'm not in the developer program so I can't try it.

See section Managing Your Media
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/ManagingYourData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH12-SW20

Comment: Why is it just for local files? It is said [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/ManagingYourData.html) under **The Movie Object (WKInterfaceMovie)** that "The URL you specify for your media assets may refer to a local file or an asset located on a remote server. For remote assets, the movie object downloads the movie completely before playing it." so it should be possible even though I wasn't be able to implement it successfully, yet.

Answer (score 1):

It only works with **https URLs**, regardless of the App Transport Security (ATS) settings.

Source [WatchKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:options:completion:):

> If you specify a URL for a file on a remote server, this method downloads the file first and displays a progress indicator showing the progress of the operation. Because WatchKit uses App Transport Security (ATS) when downloading files from a web server, the file must be on a secure server, and the URL must use the https scheme. If your server does not support ATS–level security, download the file yourself before playing it.